# org.w3c.dom.Node.insertBefore: NullPointerException, Bug?

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, android-xml

The description of org.w3c.dom.Node.insertBefore of the Android-SDK say the following:

`public abstract Node insertBefore (Node newChild, Node refChild) 

  Inserts the node newChild before the existing child node refChild. If refChild is null, insert newChild at the end of the list of children.`

But if I do the following I get NullPointerException that occurs in the insertBefore implementation:

```
if(doc != null && doc.getFirstChild() != null && tmpNode != null)
    doc.getFirstChild().insertBefore(tmpNode, null);
```

`WARN/System.err(11029):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.InnerNodeImpl.insertBefore(InnerNodeImpl.java:86)`

I tried this with Android 2.2 and Android 2.3.3!
For me it seems to be a bug. Can anybody confirm/reproduce that?

//edit (18.01.2012 13:05):
I created a new java-project, because I wanted to see if this works in a java application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder;

        try {
            docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document d = docBuilder.newDocument();

            if(d != null){
                d.appendChild(d.createElement("root"));
                if(d.getFirstChild() != null){
                    d.getFirstChild().insertBefore(d.createElement("foo"), null);
                    System.out.println(d.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This code works perfectly.

I also created a new android project to test this again:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder;

    try {
        docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document d = docBuilder.newDocument();

        if(d != null){
            d.appendChild(d.createElement("root"));
            if(d.getFirstChild() != null){
                d.getFirstChild().insertBefore(d.createElement("foo"), null);
                System.out.println(d.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When the application reaches the insertBefore, the Exception shown above is thrown.

So the same code works in normal Java, but not in Android. For me it still seems that it is a bug in the apache harmony implementation of org.w3c.dom. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'll bet it's your code, not the library.  Learning that you are the problem is a long, hard lesson.

Comment: Of course it could be that it is my fault. That why I ask the question here first (before I submit a bug) and ask for help or someone to reproduce that. But thats not the first problem I have with the apache-harmony implementation of org.w3c.dom in android - there are other bugs or gaps in implementation as well which have already been confirmed by the developers and which made my life harder^^. So maybe a have some prejudices^^

Answer (score 3):

It can be reproduced even with 4.1.2
Implementation for insertBefore from org.apache.harmony.xml.dom is

```
public Node insertBefore(Node newChild, Node refChild) throws DOMException {
    LeafNodeImpl refChildImpl = (LeafNodeImpl) refChild;

    if (refChildImpl.document != document) {
        throw new DOMException(DOMException.WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR, null);
    }

    if (refChildImpl.parent != this) {
        throw new DOMException(DOMException.HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR, null);
    }

    return insertChildAt(newChild, refChildImpl.index);
}
```

As you can see no one checks if `refChildImpl` is null so  `refChildImpl.document!=document` throws `NullPointerException`
This implementation does not make any sense if following is correct

The description of [org.w3c.dom.Node.insertBefore](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) of the Android-SDK says the following:

> public abstract Node insertBefore (Node newChild, Node refChild)
>
> Inserts the node newChild before the existing child node refChild. If
>   refChild is null, insert newChild at the end of the list of children.

Answer (score 0):

Add `doc!=null` in the if statement. It seems your doc object is null.

Comment: I added doc!=null, but I get the same exception. I'm quite sure that it is a bug, because the whole code works if a give a valid Node as second parameter. I'll add this doc!=null check also in my original post so that it is clear for other readers.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround.** Needed since [answer by ljupce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13351813/5221149) confirms it's a bug in older versions of Android.

Since [`node.insertBefore(newChild, null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#insertBefore-org.w3c.dom.Node-org.w3c.dom.Node-) doesn't work, but is the same as [`node.appendChild(newChild)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild-org.w3c.dom.Node-), the workaround is to simply call `appendChild()` when you would otherwise have called `insertBefore()` with a null `refChild` parameter.

Example:

```
// Before
node.insertBefore(newChild, refChild);

// After
if (refChild != null)
    node.insertBefore(newChild, refChild);
else
    node.appendChild(newChild);
```